# In-App Message Crashing after receiving the message

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

It's implemented the same way the documentation requires, but it thrown a message when it tries to display the message.

```
E: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my.customer, PID: 3841
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to query the maximum insets for IME
        at android.view.WindowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.java:356)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat$Impl30.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsetsCompat.java:1347)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsetsCompat.java:697)
        at androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat.hasInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.java:269)
        at com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.iam.IamFullImageFillActivity.onApplyWindowInsets(Unknown Source:16)
        at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$Api21Impl$1.onApplyWindowInsets(ViewCompat.java:4764)
        at android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View.java:11309)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7320)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.newDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7345)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7327)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.newDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7345)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7327)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:2291)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2419)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

has anyone seen this before?

Comment: What is the app version if its below 7, kindly update to Android (7.4.1) (https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/)...

Answer (score 2):

This was resolved in [Version 7.3.1](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/#version-731).  Please update your application to use the SDK v7.3.1 or greater.